# Vim: insert text from a file at current cursor position

Tags: vim

To insert text from a file in the current Vim buffer I use `:r filename` to insert the text below the cursor or `:0r filename` to insert in the first line.

How do you insert the contents of a file where [Cursor] is located?

```
Actual line with some coding [Cursor]  // TODO for later version  
Line below actual line ...
```

Comment: This is especially interesting for vim scripts/macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert a line break, read the file, and then take out the line break...

Comment: Or just use `:.-1read <file>` :) This is just like `p` and `P`, both behaviours are logical but you want to be able to do it both ways.

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a rephrasing of the question. An answer would show you HOW to do it.

Answer (score 41):

This inserts the contents of the file whose path is at the cursor position:

```
:r <cfile>
```

Comment: Thats more like below the cursor. `:.-1read <file>` can be used to place the text above the cursor (that will give you the feeling that it's placed at the cursor position).

Comment: Neither of these solutions insert text at the current cursor position. `:r <cfile>` inserts on the line below the current line, and `:.-1read <file>` inserts on the line above the current line. The question asked is how to insert AT the current cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

I propose <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> `= join(readfile('filename','b'), "\n")`

Other solution:

Possibly open the other file in another window, use `:%yh` (`h` is a register name) and in your original file, in normal mode use `"hp` or `"hP` or in insert mode, <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

### To expand on the accepted answer with actual code, since I tried the suggestion and it worked nicely;

Here is an example of it working to insert a little php snippet:

```
`nnoremap <leader>php a<CR><ESC>:.-1read $SNIPPETS/php<CR>I<BS><ESC>j0i<BS><ESC>l`
```

In general the syntax is

```
`nnoremap [KEY SEQUENCE] a<CR><ESC>:.-1read [FILE PATH]<CR>I<BS><ESC>j0i<BS><ESC>l`
```

---

## Just to break it down:

`nnoremap` : I'm about to define a new key mapping for normal mode

`<leader>php` : I would like to trigger the command sequence when this key combination is pressed. In my case `<leader>` is `,` so I type `,php` to trigger the command.

Now for the command, bit by bit:

`a<CR><ESC>` : go into insert mode (after the cursor), insert a line break, go back into normal mode.

`:.-1read <file><CR>` : this enters the desired file on the line above the current line.

`I<BS><ESC>` : jump to the start of the line, delete line break, return to normal mode.

`j0i<BS><ESC>l` : Go down one line (to the remainder of the line that you were initially on), jump to the start, enter insert mode, delete the line break, return to normal mode.

`l` : position the cursor to the right of the pasted file (this just made the command work more like how you expect it to).

---

## note

You have a choice of whether to paste before or after the cursor. I have chosen in this example to paste after the cursor because that is how the `p` command usually works to paste yanked text. Alternately, to paste before the cursor you should change the `a` at the start of the command to an `i`. You could use one of these exclusively, or you could bind them both to different but related key sequences. For example:

```
`nnoremap <leader>php i<CR><ESC>:.-1read $SNIPPETS/php<CR>I<BS><ESC>j0i<BS><ESC>l`
```

Could paste text before the cursor,

and :

```
`nnoremap <leader><leader>php a<CR><ESC>:.-1read $SNIPPETS/php<CR>I<BS><ESC>j0i<BS><ESC>l`
```

could paste text after the cursor. Or vice versa. I have made 'before the cursor' easier to trigger because I use it more often when pasting in-line.

---

## other note

This solution is mainly useful if you're reading from a file that you expect to use often enough that it's worthwhile setting up a key mapping for it (ie reading a snippet from a file). This doesn't really help if you just want to read in a random files whenever since you won't have the key mapping ready.

Since it is very formulaic, I'm sure it would be possible to define a function that would take the file name as an argument and do the same thing though. I've never written a function in vimscript though so if someone who knows more feels like editing this answer to contain that solution - I urge them to do so!

Answer (score 0):

we can copy and paste lines from one file to another file in vi or vim editor
steps: select the lines press "yh" close the file open another file press "hp" in the desired loction

Answer (score -2):

```
" put this in your ~/.vimrc
" in insert mode press ,n
"
imap ,n <c-r>=expand("%:p")<cr>
```

Read more in [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_filename).

Comment: This is not what has been asked for. OP does not want to insert current file name but to insert another file contents.